# Json Serializer for .netcore ant .Net3.5

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core

Is there any json serializer library that work in .netcore and .Net3.5?

I need to use a library in a multiplatform project the problem is that Newtonsoft's library works only in .Net Framework and System.Text.Json only works in .netcore.

** I tried Json.Net but no luck. I get this kind of error on all of the libraries:

[image]

Comment: "Newtonsoft's library works only in .Net Framework" - that's not true, Newtonsoft.Json has supported .NET Core ever since Core started.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, NewtonSoft works also for .NET Standard

Comment: Sadly I think you would have to be really lucky to find something that works with .Net 3.5 seeing as it came out in 2002, the json standard was published in 2017

Comment: @MarkDavies got a reference on those publishing dates? Only asking because what you're saying contradicts the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) article on JSON with a few years (it's been around since ealy 2000s, but standardized in 2013).

Comment: @MarkDavies: .NET 3.5 came out in 2007, and RFC 7158 came out in 2013. So instead of a 15 year gap, it's only a 6 year gap. And the latest version of Json.NET supports even .NET 2.0.

Comment: Json.NET is *required* by all ASP.NET Core applications up to .NET Core 2.2. If you check [its NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) you'll see it's compatible with all .NET and .NET Core versions since .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: What version of .NET CORE are you using?

Comment: I get this error : Package Json.Net 1.0.18 is not compatible with net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5). Package Json.Net 1.0.18 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

Comment: @roozbehS the latest JSON.NET version is 12.0.3. Where did you even find 1.0.18? It's not on NuGet. NuGet only goes down to the 8 year old 3.5.8

Comment: @roozbehS that screenshot doesn't say anything either, especially if you added some downloaded extra-old binary. The [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) clearly shows the supported runtimes. Add the package with NuGet, not by downloading binaries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, but earlier you suggested Json.Net not Newtonsof.Json. So, the one I am using in the screenshot is not Newtonsoft.Josn, it's Json.Net from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Json.Net/ and 1.0.18 is the latest version.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I went back to Newtonsoft and I think I found the problem. No idea how this happened but the package was added under <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.2'">! So I deleted the condition and everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataContractJsonSerializer`

I am using it in my .net standard library to serialize and de-serialize my model objects to json.

```
public static string PrepareJsonString<T>(object objectToBeParsed)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        string json = string.Empty;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(ms, (T)objectToBeParsed);
            ms.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return json;
    }

public static object PrepareObjectFromString<T>(string json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var deSerializedUser = dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            return deSerializedUser;
        }
    }
```

sample to consume this functions

```
List<MyModel>  list=  PrepareObjectFromString<List<MyModel>>(myJson);
                       or
MyModel  list=  PrepareObjectFromString<MyModel>(myJson);

string json=PrepareJsonString<MyModel>(myModelInstance);
```

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: That was a stop-gap class that didn't even handle dates properly. If you use that in .NET Standard libraries, where JSON.NET isn't only supported, it's actually a *requirement* in web app projects, you're introducing incompatibilities in your code without a reason

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, iam not getting it clearly. My .net standard library doesn't support web project , it's going to support uwp , xamarin, unity etc.. but not web. Can you please explain why should not I use it in .net standard , so that i can change it .

Comment: Because it's obsolete and never meant to be a general purpose JSON serializer - it's buggy. That's why everyone uses JSON.NET Even *Microsoft* doesn't use DataContractJsonSerializer. It was only meant to be used for the very-short-lived WCF Ajax services

Comment: JSON .NET is an third party library , right? is there any in build serializer available in .net ?!

Comment: Even ASP.NET Web API uses JSON.NET, and all ASP.NET Core 2.0 versions up to 2.2. It's the defacto standard used by Microsoft itself. Nobody uses DataContractJsonSerializer. It has bugs. If you want a built-in JSON serializer, System.Text.Json only became available in .NET Core 3.0

Comment: To put it another way: do you want to create an incompatible library *and* really annoy users? Use the obsolete serializer. Do you want to create a library that everyone can use without actually adding anything, because the *already* use that serializer? Use JSON.NET